# Encrypted QR Code Reader/Generator

Tags: encryption, qr-code

As a part of my final year project, i plan to develop a customized qr code encoder/decoder which would generate Encrypted QR Codes. Not having much knowledge in encryption i just wanted to know if any algorithm like RC4 can be implemented on a mobile device given the resource constraints. Also if not on mobile device, would it be possible to develop a qr reader/generator for pc ? If yes, any info on any libraries that can be used ?

Just to be clear, by encrypted i mean, original message-->encryption-->encrypted message-->generate QR Code for encrypted message-->encrypted qr code

Receiver side: encrypted qr code-->qr code reader-->encrypted message-->decryption-->original message.

Comment: In what language / platform?

Comment: Why RC4 and not something AES based?

Comment: During my literature review, i found that aes has already been implemented in this regard, so my mentor suggested using this and later comparing the performances of both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is a smartphone powerful enough to run RC4 over a few hundred bytes of data? By many orders of magnitude, yes. Think about how much processing it takes to support the HTTPS connection you probably just used on a mobile web site.  Or, consider that decoding a QR code already requires Reed-Solomon decoding over the same data, which is about as complex. Even 100K operations is next to nothing on a 1GHz chip.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Also can the Zxing project be used for developing QR code Encoder/Decoder for pc or laptop using an external web camera or the inbuilt camera of the laptop ?

Comment: Yes, it has implementations of both. The work is to get access to the webcam image in a Java program on the computer. That I don't know, but if you can get a `BufferedImage` you're done.

Comment: Thank you so much, i can now convince my mentor to let me go forward with this !